# Cancelling IDBOpenDBRequest?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, indexeddb, abort

I have the following snippet of code:

```js
function open_db(dbname, dbversion, upgrade, onblocked) {
    if (upgrade === undefined) {
        upgrade = function basic_init(ev) {
            …
        };
    }
    if (onblocked === undefined) {
        onblocked = function onblocked(ev) {
            throw ev;
        };
    }
    let req = window.indexedDB.open(dbname, dbversion);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        req.onsuccess = ev => resolve(ev.target.result);
        req.onerror = ev => reject(ev.target.error);
        req.onupgradeneeded = ev => {
            try {
                return upgrade(ev);
            } catch (error) {
                reject(error);
                ev.target.onsuccess = ev => ev.target.close(); // IS THIS LINE NECESSARY?
                throw error; // IS THIS LINE UNNECESSARY?
            }
        };
        req.onblocked = ev => {
            try {
                return onblocked(ev);
            } catch (error) {
                reject(error);
                ev.target.onsuccess = ev => ev.target.close(); // IS THIS LINE NECESSARY?
                throw error; // IS THIS LINE UNNECESSARY?
            }
        };
    });
}
```

If the `.onblocked` or `.onupgradeneeded` handlers `throw` a native error, will that cancel the open attempt? Or will the [`IDBOpenDBRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBOpenDBRequest) object ignore such errors and steam on ahead obliviously until I manually close the db if/after it's opened?

In a nutshell: are the commented lines of code necessary? Are they *sufficient* to prevent a dangling open handle?

Is there a better way to *cancel* the request-to-open, rather than just adding `.onsuccess = ev => … .close()`?

Answer (score 2):

You're asking the right question (*"Is there a better way to cancel the request-to-open... ?"*) and the answer is: no, not as currently defined/implemented. All you can do is make the open a no-op by aborting the upgrade.

Throwing in a `blocked` handler doesn't have specified special behavior; doing anything here should be unnecessary, as it will be followed by an `upgradeneeded` eventually.

On `upgradeneeded`, closing the connection before the upgrade completes will terminate the request and abort the upgrade, so the version won't change. There are a handful of ways to do this:

- call close on the connection (`db = e.target.result; db.close();`)

  - Defined by:
    https://w3c.github.io/IndexedDB/#open-a-database - *If connection was closed...*
- abort the transaction explicitly (`tx = e.target.transaction; tx.abort();`)

  - Defined by: https://w3c.github.io/IndexedDB/#open-a-database - *If the upgrade transaction was aborted...*
- abort the transaction implicitly by throwing within the `upgradeneeded` event handler.

  - Defined by: https://w3c.github.io/IndexedDB/#run-an-upgrade-transaction - *If didThrow is true...*

Note that after seeing `upgradeneeded`, waiting until `success` (which your code does) means the transaction will have completed, and the upgrade will have happened.

So in your sample code, the `throw` statements *are* effectual (they will abort the upgrade), while the `close` calls are *not*. The `success` event should never fire, in that case, which makes adding handlers for `success` which close the connection irrelevant.

Comment: >_closing the connection before the upgrade completes_< by this, do you mean that `db.close` is called before `onupgradeneeded` `return`s?

Comment: _n.b._ for anyone else reading this answer: [`IDBRequest.transaction`](https://w3c.github.io/IndexedDB/#dom-idbrequest-transaction) _is_ a getter attribute that returns the _current_ transaction, and does _not_ create a new one like [`IDBDatabase.transaction`](https://w3c.github.io/IndexedDB/#dom-idbdatabase-transaction) does. (That confused me until I hunted around in the spec and found the definitions of each.)

Comment: "do you mean that db.close is called before onupgradeneeded returns?"

Any time before the upgrade transaction commits. So you could issue a request in the upgradeneeded callback, and call close() before or when that request's success callback fires. The upgrade transaction is like other transactions - it'll stay alive as long as you keep issuing requests against it, and try to commit once it has no more outstanding requests. This probably isn't useful in the context of the original question, though, which is trying to "cancel" the open as quickly as possible.